# Surveys, Papers, Hand on Tutorials about training data generation for anomaly detection

Tags: unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, anomaly-detection, semi-supervised-learning, novelty-search

I am searching for anything related to supervised, semi supervised or unsupervised anomaly detection w.r.t training data generation.

I am looking toward reading any work that tackles the issue how to generate a training/test dataset for anomaly detection.

If someone knows any work related to the subject above, please share it with me.

Regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Like how? I mean, I've already found one but only one paper that exactaly is about my question.